# Use spaces in parameter used in script called by a command

Tags: bash

I need to run a Bash command with a script calling parameters: `comm1 ./script.sh param1 param2 param3`.
Script includes this: `timeout 10 bash -c "  comm2  ./param1.param3"`.  It indicates that param1 file is in the current directory.

And it works as long as param1 is a single word. But I need it to be a file name which can have spaces.
So command should be: `comm1 ./script.sh "param1\ with\ space" param2 param3` . No dot and extension in file name, just spaces are problem and maybe brackets.

I don't know how to modify param1 to be able to use spaces in this case, and if script should also be modified. Thanks for help.

Comment: `printf -v cmd_line '%q ' comm2 "$1" "$2"` will generate a `$cmd_line` that's correctly quoted with spaces from `$1` or `$2` escaped. Thereafter, you can run `timeout 10 bash -c "$cmd_line"`

Comment: ...however, I do agree with Kaffe that it's not obvious why you're calling an intermediary copy of `bash` at all, instead of `timeout 10 comm2 "$1" "$2"` -- when you don't wrap things in `bash -c` you don't need the extra escaping in the first place.

Comment: I call bash first because `comm2  ./param1  param2` really is `pre-comm2-param comm2  ./param1  param2 ` meaning command has a special parameter before, so it didn't work all without bash -c.

Comment: I'd need to know that your "special parameter" really is for that to make sense. A redirection? An environment variable assignment? Either way there's an option available that doesn't require an extra copy of bash (_what_ that option is depending on the details of what the "special parameter" is). Only if it's an exported shell function wrapper do you really, unavoidably need a shell.

Comment: It's an environment variable for comm2.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to quote and escape the parameters, send the parameters to `bash -c`.

```
timeout 10 bash -c 'comm2 "$@"' bash "$1" "$2"
```

This will set $0 to "bash" and the first two parameters to the values of the first two positional parameters of the script.

Comment: True, but `comm2` (parsed as a shell script, being the argument directly after `-c`) doesn't _inspect_ `$1` and `$2` so they just get thrown away. Maybe you want `timeout 10 bash -c 'comm2 "$@"' bash "$1" "$2"`?

Comment: I use parameters like this:  `timeout 10 bash -c '  comm2 ' ./"param1"."param3"`   I have to indicate to comm2 that it's a filename. I see echo of `timeout 10 bash -c 'comm2' './$1.$2'` which may mean that replacement is done correctly, but really it doesn't work. Comm2 doesn't open that file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Exactly, copy-paste problem on my side.

Comment: Working with `comm1 ./script.sh "param1 with space" param2 param3` , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure on the exact reason to call bash first.

The easiest answer is to simply skip the bash call:

```sh
timeout 10 comm2 "./param with.spaces" param2
```

If you want to reuse the logic in several places, make a function.

```sh
timesup() { timeout 10 "$@" ;}

timesup comm2 "./param with.spaces" param2
```

whatever command you throw, the function will parse it the same way

If you really need to call bash first for whatever reason, you could mix quotation:

```sh
timeout 10 bash -c "comm2 './param with.spaces' param2"
```

Comment: As `command` is itself a built-in command included in the shell, it might make more sense to leave the OP's distinct placeholder name in place unless you mean to instruct people to use that builtin.

Comment: `comm` is, incidentally, _also_ a standard command)

Comment: Hahaha. the first was just a miss. but `comm` I didn't know off!

Comment: Looks simple, but somehow it does OK a few iterations and then just stalls, not sure how. I used `comm1 ./script.sh "param1 with space" param2` and saw with echo this:  `timeout 10 bash -c 'comm2 '\''./param1 with space'\''.param2'` It's all single quotes.